# How does Wowhead.com do item popups across fansites?

Tags: jquery, json, jsonp

If you run a site that links to world of warcraft items, you're probably using the wowhead.com javascript to bring their item popups to your site. [See it in action here](http://bighitbox.com/bhb/2009/3/30/pre-raid-enhance-gear.html), mouse over the "King Dred's Helm" link. It will popup Wowhead.com's info.

is this just a jsonp callback to their site?

I want to implement something like this on my site. Perhaps it could be done using jQuery html fragment and a jsonp callback to my own site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it's JSON or ajax call

Comment: so theoretically, I do a jsonp callback to my site... use jQuery to build an html fragment on their site? How about styling? Do it inline or ask site owner to copy a bit of css to their stylesheets?

Answer (score 1):

If you want this exact functionality check out this article on [how to add wowhead tooltips](http://www.wowhead.com/tooltips) on your site.

But, if you are after a generic tooltip, I'd definitely recommend [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/), which can handle dynamic tooltip content.

Comment: Ah, I didn't mean I wanted to use wowhead on my site. But thanks for the link. ;D I was referring to "How?" did they do it. And yes, qTip rocks.